# Reverbs in sound effects library

Tags: reverb, sound-effects

Hi,

sometimes when I listen to some library demos I notice deep and powerful reverbs, especially on hit and impacts. I would mind if those sounds are delivered dry or with reverbs.

Thanks,
Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Boom library](http://www.boomlibrary.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=5) tends to produce sfx packages with both raw elements (labeld construction kits) and fully processed and layered sounds (labeled designed).

I personally think this is a good approach, since sometimes the immediacy of having a fully designed sound already put together is appropriate given certain budgets and timelines, and other times you really want the base elements so you can build something fresh and tailored.

Also, I'll note that in many of the sounds that I personally end up using when building hits and impacts the raw elements are actually recorded in a reverberant space, so there's that.

Answer (score 1):

ok I will try to remember

Comment: ah, so that is you? please stop doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Great point, Luca.  I personally avoid any processing and let the editor/designer decide what is appropriate.

I wonder what the community prefers regarding reverb and compression?  Add reverb and compression?  Leave it out?  Should a library supply two versions - processed and dry?

Paul Virostek

Comment: Only dry plz! No compression, just normalising. But there's something to say for the combined approach as well, as described in the answer below about Boom Library.

Answer (score 1):

Sound libraries released for film editors (with little to no audio skill) tend to be fully processed and designed.  It's possible that's what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

I used to like sound ideas before i developed the ear for all the wierd subliminal sounsd in there and now it's half useless because the sounds aren't raw but are a creation by sound ideas sound designers.  my friend jessica is coming out with a library soon that should have what we are all looking for.